# Looking for a way to Calculate Frequency distribution of a dataframe in spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to calculate the frequency distribution(return most common element in each column and the number of times it appeared) of a dataframe using spark and scala. I've tried using DataFrameStatFunctions library but after I filter my dataframe for only numeric type columns, I cant apply any functions from the library. Is the best way to do this to create a UDF?

Answer (score 12):

you can use 

`val newDF = df.groupBy("columnName").count()
newDF.show()`

it will show you the frequency count for unique entries.